# How to hide/show custom Fileupload in asp.net using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I have a styled file Upload laying on top the vanilla asp.net fileupload control, which is hidden.
If the user comes back to edit his chosen files, there are buttons to view the file or delete it from the dataset; In addition the  control is hidden.
However the fake fileupload remains visible.
I have written a custom method to call Jquery from Code behind, but I'm lacking the Jquery skills to hide this fake control and show it on demand.

The task is: Hide the fileupload which is contained in a  and show it again if the user clicks on "remove file" & set the  control to visible again, so he can choose another file.

Kind regards.

edit: the c# Method containing the Jquery code looks like this right now:

```
runjQueryCode(@"$(document).ready(function() {
                 $('#" + Btn_removeFile.ClientID + @"').click(function(){
                    $('.fakefile').show();
                    $('"+ fu.ClientID +@"').show();
                  });
                    $('.fakefile').hide();
                    $('"+ fu.ClientID +@"').hide();
                  });");
```

Comment: Show the code you have written...

Comment: sorry, just realized the same.

Comment: what is runjQueryCode? and are you writting Jquery from CodeBehind?

Comment: yes, cant avoid it sometimes, because I dondt have time to refactor all the code which has somebody written before me.

Comment: please see my answer..check wheather you can do by that way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is as follow...It will show the FileUpload if it is already hidden and will hide if it is already visible...

**CodeBehind:-**

```
Btn_removeFile.Attributes["onClick"] = "ShowHideFileUpload('"+fu.ClientID+"');"
```

**Javascript:-**

```
function ShowHideFileUpload(fuID)
{
   if($(fuID).is(":visible"))
   {
        $('.fakefile').hide(); 
        $(fuID).hide(); 
   }
   else
   {
       $('.fakefile').show(); 
       $(fuID).show();     
   }    
}
```

Comment: this doenst work, because the removeFile button already has onClick method attached.

Comment: your solution did partially work, but the error is nested in the existing messed up code I have to deal with; works fine in a clean aspx file.
Because I'm short on time I told my superior to get a designer to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery("#a").show(); To Show it.

jQuery("#a").hide(); To hide it.

a would be id of your fileupload control. You are calling it from custom method in code behind then no need to bind it to any click event. Just call it on demand from code behind.

Use FileUpload1.ClientID for a.

Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "dtp", "$('.fakefile').show();$('#"+ fu.ClientID +@"').show();", true);